# How to improve quality of images taken from different resolution devices - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on an application where we are dealing with lots of images (Capturing , uploading, downloading from the server and displaying them).
If we are capturing images from iOS or any big resolution of Android devices, the captured images are coming properly without losing the quality.
But I am facing problem when images are getting captured from low end devices having low resolutions. (Android's lower end devices)
Is there any way to handle such scenario where irrespective of device resolution the image should not loose the quality.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much stuck with the camera capabilities for that device. If the device has a camera that is 3.2MP, then it will only be able to create an image with a maximum resolution of 2048 × 1536, give or take.

Basically, you can downgrade an image's resolution, not upgrade whilst limited by the device's hardware.